# How to run a python script on images present in firebase?

Tags: python, firebase, heroku, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I have a image in my firebase acccount and I want to run a python script on this image and get a result back.

Can someone suggest me a simple way to do this?

I tried hosting the python file in heroku. Fetching the image from firebase to heroku and running the python script would be an overhead.

Is there a simpler way to run the python script in firebase itself?

Comment: What is your actual question? Have you tried writing any code? Like even accessing Firebase with Python, etc? SO is for solving specific reproducible problems, not very broad issues like this.

Answer (score 0):

There are a handful of Python wrappers for Firebase but some have not been updated in awhile. Try this [Getting Started with Pyrebase](https://github.com/thisbejim/Pyrebase#getting-started), then try this tutorial for [Getting started on Heroku with Python](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-python#introduction).